# Android scrollTo does not work in complicated view hierarchy

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollto

I have the following View hierarchy:

```
CoordinatorLayout
<include statement (other file begins here)>
RelativeLayout
NestedScrollView
RelativeLayout
<include view above recyclerview that mimics a recycler card item>
<include view above recyclerview that mimics a second recycler card item>
RecyclerView
```

Now, I need to scroll to a specific index of the RecyclerView adapater dataset but none of the following code works:

```
    recycler.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
             //scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, ((int) recycler.getChildAt(pos).getY()));
             //recycler.scrollToPosition(pos);
             linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(pos);
        }
    });//, 250);
```

I figure it *might* have something to do with the nesting of the recyclerview inside the scrollview, but I really have no idea. The reason there is a nestedscrollview at all is because the two include statements before my recyclerview are actually cardviews that control the dataset of the recyclerview. The user can hide these two cards at any time, and there is a fade animation that brings the recyclerview up to the position where the card was. If that sounds complicated, it is, and I think including these "control cards" as I call them would be less efficient, harder to animate and significantly harder to work with if I included them as different view types in the recycler instead of placing them independently above it, as I have them now.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling like this

```
yourRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(pos);    
            }
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have that almost exactly already. I've posted code.